# Where to salvage inductors?

Tags: inductor, high-voltage, high-frequency, high-current, flyback

I need a toroidal inductor for my ZVS flyback driver. The value should be between 47uH to 200uH. It should be able to handle 6A. Where can I salvage them from?

Comment: you might findo something in switchin ATX psu's. You'll probably need to rewind them... Anyway, remember that working frequency is a pretty important parameter too.

Comment: I agree with Vladimir, a PSU from almost any computer old or new will have high enough current rated inductor for a flyback switchmode circuit of your own.

Comment: If I don't find one, I can wind my own. Is there another place where I can get even a core or something besides a PSU?

Comment: Amidon has a decent selection of cores, and almost everyone carries some.

Comment: If you're that specific on what you're looking for, why not just pony up and buy one? You could spend a lot of time trying to salvage a suitable part...

Comment: I visited the marke twice. They only keep like 2 foot large ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I don't find one, I can wind my own.
>   Is there another place where I can get even a core or something besides a PSU?

For high power use a custom designed powdered iron core is usually superior to ferrite.

As well as power supplies, modern "PC" motherboards often have on board buck converters that provide the high current at very low voltages required by modern CPUs. The cores used are liable to be optimised for high frequency smps use but as they operate at high frequencies (100's of kHz+ ) and high current their inductance is liable to be low. Rewindability will depend on construction but some will be able to be rewound.

As well as PC type main power supplies there are a vast number of other power supplies available that have cores that may suit. Laptop power supplies are typically rate in the 50 - 100 Watt range with cores liable to be suitable. Even dead supplies are unlikely to have damaged inductor cores.

Modern "CFL" light bulbs contain high frequency inverters with potentially useful cores. If you have several dead bulbs of the same type you may be able to combine several cores to make a larger effective one.

"Electronic ballasts" for halogen and LED lighting are usually mains to 12V or other inverters with cores of possible use.

12V and 24V DC to mains AC inverters tend to cost little and die young and are a potential source of possible cores.

Printers, copiers and commercial electronic equipment of many sorts often liable to have substantial internal power supplies. [Finding a dead one is liable to be preferred to attacking the office copier :-). ]

Comment: I found a ferrite rod in a old radio. Can I wind a coil around it to make it work?

Comment: @Avz RF cores not on my list you'll note. It will have some effect relative to air, and probably will not do anything bad, but results are liable to be much closer to air than most of what I suggested. If you are dealing with 6A (at unspecified voltage) the design is non trivial - the inductor is a core part (pun noted) and needs to be better designed and designable than you seem to be aaiming at.

Comment: It's at 24V. I can have it at anything from 47uH to 200uH. Accuracy isn't very important.

Comment: @AvZ An air core or an RF ferrite core or any core with a non closed magnetic path will tend to radiate and cause EM noise issues. A low mu core will need more turns so more resistance or larger core or more wire or ... or some or all of these. Posting your circuit is usually felt to be "a good idea".

Comment: I am using this circuit. I have the same components except the inductor itself. [link](http://www.instructables.com/file/FIYEAZNG9NH8XOG)

Comment: I have created a new question for this here - [link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/107531/value-of-inductor)