# Value of inductor

Tags: rf, design, inductor, magnetics, ferrite

I need to wind an inductor with a value between 47uH - 200uH. I have a 10 mm (in diameter) ferrite core from an RF choke used in an old radio (probably lossy ferrite). The core is 3 cm long (I also have a 5 cm long core too though). I will be using 19SWG magnet wire to wind the coil. How many turns do I need? I will be using the inductor for a ZVS flyback driver [(Schematic)](http://www.instructables.com/file/FIYEAZNG9NH8XOG). My power supply is 24V @ 6A.

Comment: You need at least know magnetic permeability of your ferrite.

Comment: The value doesn't have to be accurate. I'd say it is on the lower side of the ferrite permeability spectrum, though.

Comment: So, did you tried any inductor calculators? Did they give inconsistent results?

Comment: ...You may use ferrite rod antenna equations for your task.

Comment: I didn't find any for ferrite cores. If you know any, would you share a link, please?

Comment: Do you have a link for a ferrite rod antenna equations?

Comment: There are some links found by this search request https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ferrite+rod+inductance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XaJWU77UMK2dwAPJ3IDoCQ There are some relevant results. Have you troubles with them?

Comment: I think that ferrite from old radio may (or not) oversaturate and not work as desired. Notice 10 Amps guys.

Comment: I don't have a device to measure inductance, so I guess I would have to use the hit and trial method. As for the oversaturation, I saw a video of the same driver, but the guy was running at 15A. He had a very thin ferrite rod, and it worked fine for him. I'll give it a try within a few days. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If magnetic permeability of ferrite core is unknown - you have to wind it and measure it.

That may be complicated without oscilloscope or multimeter with inductor measurement.

In addition - I think RF ferrite may not work. Radio ferrites are not designed to store so much energy. It probably oversaturate and not work as desired at high current.

It will be even harder to determine if that happens without oscilloscope.

I think it would be easier to use some inductor with few thick windings from ATX power supply or other DC/DC converter and try how good or bad your converter is by measuring power efficiency.

Power input:

$$P_{in} = I_{in} \times U_{in}$$

Power output:

$$P_{out} = I_{out} \times U_{out}$$

Efficiency:

$$n = \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$

That kind of flyback converter should have 65%-75% efficiency.

However if coil is very badly chosen and you have big power supply - you may blow up transistors because energy must go somewhere when back EMF happens on big transformer. Maybe try with smaller (1A?) power supply first and check transistors temperature.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with a smaller supply then. By the way, does the length of the core matter? If I have a longer piece, will that prevent saturation?

Comment: Generally - mass of core inside your coil matters. Shape matters (closed magnetic circuit or not). Everything matters :)

Answer (score 2):

The circuit below is the one you linked to. This makes the question clearer and would have been good to see from the start.

[image]

The inductor is relatively non critical - it is not really part of the oscillator proper but serves to provide a high AC impedance path to feed DC by. If you were using a ferrite core there you could instead just use an air wound inductor. Both will result in you having a substantial RF transmitter. Using a large electrolytic capacitor on the DC input will help somewhat, but ideally you want to use an iron powder cored toroid there. You could use an old iron core transformer with relatively few turns and an airgap to improve current handling and stop the core saturating.

This actual circuit diagram is posted by many people but none seem to refer to the originator. You'll see that most use a toroid there.

---

**Related:**

- [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/ZVS-Driver/) - possibly your source
- [Good discussion here](http://adammunich.com/zvs-driver/) but with some incorrect stuff. Useful.
- [Another *instructables*](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-ZVS-driver/) - same CCT diagram image. Note toroid.
- [ZVS Flyback Driver](http://gaugeboson.com/electronics/high_voltage.html) - Useful. Note toroid.
- [Useful discussion at 4HV.org](http://4hv.org/e107_plugins/forum/forum_viewtopic.php?69563.post)
- [Another discussion at 4HV.org](http://4hv.org/e107_plugins/forum/forum_viewtopic.php?104472.0#post_104600)
- [Various CCTs](http://uzzors2k.4hv.org/index.php?page=flybacktransformerdrivers) - this one and others
- [Same CCT](http://pocketmagic.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/zvs-flyback-driver/) - note toroid
- [Same CCT and others](http://pocketmagic.wordpress.com/tag/zvs/)